# Adding php values from database in custom css file

Tags: php, css, opencart, opencart-3

I am using Opencart v 3.0.3.0

In database, one separate table is created with css values in it.

In stylesheet folder, `view/stylesheet/custom_css.php` file is added.

`custom_css.php` file code is somewhat like below...

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
.content {
    color: <?php echo $data['content_color'];?>; // which is #333 saved in database
    padding : 10px;
    background-color:  <?php echo $data['content_bgcolor'];?>;
 }
 .mydiv {
    border:  <?php echo $data['mydiv_border'];?>; // which is 1px solid #ccc saved in database
    margin : 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    text-shadow: <?php echo $data['mydiv_textshadow'];?>; 
 }
```

I added this file in `controller/extension/module/custom_css.php` after fetching data from database,

```
 $this->load->model('extension/module/custom_css');

 $mysetting = $this->model->extension->module->custom_css->getCssValues(); // This function works ok when tried with print_r
   foreach($mysetting as $mysettings => $val ) {            
        $data[$mysettings] = $val;            
  }

 $this->document->addStyle('view/stylesheet/custom_css.php');
```

But I am getting Undefined data error for custom_css declared php values.

Is it a right approach ? Or need something else ?

Comment: Bad idea.......

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков Please can you elaborate why it is bad idea ? And what is alternative to it ?

Comment: if the addStyle method dose not support passing params, ie `addStyle('/path/to.php', $data)`, you may be forced to use `$GLOBALS['data']`, or worse plopping into `$_SESSION` instead of `$data` in custom_css.php, track down addStyle function see how it works, perhaps you could also add to `->document->theme_props`, and it be available in the file as `$this->theme_props`, not sure do some debugging